# include C code on C++ strange error

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, include

I'm trying to use some C functions(made by me) on c++ code.
I'm using Eclipse.

**Main.cpp Code:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" {
   #include "f.h"
}
int main(){
   return 1;
}
```

Now f.h have a lot of functions, but it give me error on the ones that have this initialize line.
So my `f.h` code is only this:

```
char o[9] = "00000000\0";
```

But...

```
initializer-string for array of chars is too long   f.h
```

if I compile it in C It will work...why?

Comment: If you give a length for a `char` array in C and initialize it with exactly that many characters, no 0-terminator is appended to the string. I don't know how things are in C++, though, but I do know, that this is valid C.

Comment: yeah, infact in C is valid!
In C++ is not!

but with extern "C", I want to make it valid in C++ (but it is not working)

Comment: afaik, `extern "C"` makes function prototypes C function prototypes. I think it's mainly about the calling convention and the name mangling to use, not about what syntax is valid. But I don't know C++ that good…

Comment: btw… What is the use case? You want to use the C-feature of omitted 0-terminators in string constants and provide it manually. Why?

Comment: it's just an example, i don't want to modify all my C functions.
Of course I could rewrite them in C++, but I want load it direct in C...

Comment: If this is the initialization of an extern variable, you don't want to provide it in the header, I think. Is this actually a static variable?

Comment: originally this declaration was in a function(){char o[9] = "00000000\0";}

I deleted all to get direct to the problem.

Comment: Is this something you want to know just out of curiosity to learn about differences between C and C++ or do you have an actual use case?

Comment: Is this a static function with the implementation in the header? If not, why don't you compile your C code with a C compiler?

Comment: both.
I could rewrite for avoid the problem. But i wanna know why it happens.

maybe is fault of my compiler?

Comment: how can I compile it separated and add to c++ program?

Comment: OK. So it's a theoretical question without a real use case? Still an interesting question, but I can't answer it for C++.

Comment: You compile your object files, as always. Compile your C files with a C compiler and your C++ files with a C++ compiler (and surround your C function prototypes in the C++ headers with `extern "C"`, as you did). Then link the object files.

Comment: I don't understand. is it possibile to make it directly in eclipse, so if i make change in the codes, i don't have to waste time?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Eclipse, but I think, there is a way. But this is actually a different question (and you should tag it with "eclipse" to reach an audience knowing it).

Comment: added. thanks, i will make some research for discover something about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to copy ten characters into an array that you have defined as 9 characters long.

Try:

```
char o[9] = "00000000";
```

it is already has a null character at the end. Alternatively get the compiler to do the counting. ie.

```
char o[] = "00000000";
```

Comment: in c is valid, and i am trying to compile this header in C

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to explicitly write \0, if you are enclosing in double quotes it is treated as NULL terminated string.

Comment: in c is valid, and i am trying to compile this header in C from a c++ project

Comment: @user2903357 I have used extern "C", still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, a c-string will append a '\0' at the end automatically. So,

```
"00000000\0"
```

The real memory representation is "00000000\0\0" which is 10 bytes.

Comment: That's true only if you don't give a length explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

You told the compiler that you would provide it with 9 chars, instead you only provided it with 8, simply because the null character doesn't count when counting the chars.

```
char o[8] = "00000000\0";
```

Try that. This may also work.

```
char o[8] = "00000000";
```

Comment: Actually they provided it with 10 characters and your array is too small by 1 element.

Comment: char o[9] = "00000000\0"; in C works!

And i am trying to compile the f.h code as C not c++

Comment: @user2903357; in C, that's totally valid, see my comment to your question. I'm not sure about C++, though.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious; It _is_ valid, you are not overwriting any bounds. If you give an explicit length of N and an initializer with exactly N elements, the 0-terminator is omitted and everything is in bounds. The 0-terminator is appended only if there is enough space for it.